# Perl: show element difference in HoA's

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Is there a way just to show the individual element difference in this code scenario?  I have searched and searched and tried many lines of code for close to 4 hours.  Currently its showing the entire key:value data set that is different and all I want it to show or it needs to show is ent5:440.

Thank you!

```
use strict;
use warnings;

    my @diff = list_diff(keys %vlans_A, keys %vlans_B);
    print "Difference in keys: ", @diff, "\n" if @diff;

    KEY:
    foreach my $key (keys %vlans_A) {
        next KEY unless exists $vlans_B{$key};
        my @diff = list_diff(@{ $vlans_A{$key} },@{ $vlans_B{$key} });
        print "Difference at key $key: ", @diff, "\n" if @diff;
    }


    sub list_diff {
        my %keys;
        $keys{$_}++ for @_;
        return grep 2 != $keys{$_}, keys %keys;
    }


Difference at key ent5: 102 103 433 440 1803 1806 1808 1809 1814 1815 1822 1866 1867 1898 2002102 103 433 1803 1806 1808 1809 1814 1815 1822 1866 1867 1898 2002
$VAR1 = {
          'ent5' => [
                      '102 103 433 440 1803 1806 1808 1809 1814 1815 1822 1866 1867 1898 2002'
                    ],
          'ent4' => [
                      '409 432 434 435 436 1702 1703 1802 1805 1851 1852 1854 1855 1857 1858 1863 1864 1870 2001'
                    ],
          'ent9' => [
                      '4094'
                    ]
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'ent5' => [
                      '102 103 433 1803 1806 1808 1809 1814 1815 1822 1866 1867 1898 2002'
                    ],
          'ent4' => [
                      '409 432 434 435 436 1702 1703 1802 1805 1851 1852 1854 1855 1857 1858 1863 1864 1870 2001'
                    ],
          'ent9' => [
                      '4094'
                    ]
        };
```

Comment: The input hash values each consist of a list containing a single string. You need to use `split()` these into lists of strings each containing one number. Then diff _those_ lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach, splitting the values at white space:

```
KEY:
for my $key (keys %vlans_A) {
    next KEY unless exists $vlans_B{$key};
    my @diff = list_diff(get_values($vlans_A{$key}), get_values($vlans_B{$key}));
    print "Difference at key $key: @diff\n" if @diff;
}

sub get_values {
    my ( $key_strs ) = @_;

    my @keys;
    for my $str ( @$key_strs ) {
        push @keys, split " ", $str;
    }
    return @keys;
}

 sub list_diff {
    my %keys;
    $keys{$_}++ for @_;
    return grep 2 != $keys{$_}, keys %keys;
}
```

Comment: did you accidentally remove list diff?

Answer (score 2):

One of many ways to achieve desired desired result

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 0;

my %vlans_A;
my %vlans_B;

while( <DATA> ) {                   # load hash %vlans_A
    chomp;

    last if /__DATA__/;

    my($k,$a)       = split ':';
    @{$vlans_A{$k}} = (split ' ', $a);
}

while ( <DATA> ) {                  # load hash %vlans_B
    chomp;

    last if /__DATA__/;

    my($k,$a)       = split ':';
    @{$vlans_B{$k}} = split ' ', $a;
}

print Dumper(\%vlans_A) if $debug;
print Dumper(\%vlans_B) if $debug;

while( my($k,$v) = each %vlans_A ) {
    my %hash;

    if( @{$vlans_A{$k}} > @{$vlans_B{$k}} ) {
        @hash{sort @{$vlans_A{$k}}} = sort @{$vlans_B{$k}};     # array A has more elements
    } else {
        @hash{sort @{$vlans_B{$k}}} = sort @{$vlans_A{$k}};     # array B has more elements
    }

    while( my($el1,$el2) = each %hash ) {
        say("$k: $el1") if ! defined $el2;
        say("$k: $el2") if ! defined $el1;
    }
}

__DATA__
ent5:102 103 433 440 1803 1806 1808 1809 1814 1815 1822 1866 1867 1898 2002
ent4:409 432 434 435 436 1702 1703 1802 1805 1851 1852 1854 1855 1857 1858 1863 1864 1870 2001
ent9:4094
__DATA__
ent5:102 103 433 1803 1806 1808 1809 1814 1815 1822 1866 1867 1898 2002
ent4:409 432 434 435 436 1702 1703 1802 1805 1851 1852 1854 1855 1857 1858 1863 1864 1870 2001
ent9:4094
```